# DateTime turned to string by two methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I am trying to compare two DateTime attributes in a view, which is after the attributes have been turned into strings. Unfortunately the objects are being turned into slightly different formatted strings, and so are never able to be equal. Any adea why?

```
Version A: 2015-11-12 00:00:00 +0000 
Version B: 2015-11-12T00:00:00+00:00
```

Context in my view:

```
options_for_select(dates, selected: (f.object.start ? f.object.start.change({hour: 0}).to_s : 0))
```

Here, `dates` generates Version A

```
  def dates(first_date=DateTime.now)
    first_date = date.midnight
    dates = []
    [*0..100].each do |i|
      dates << [(first_date + i.days).strftime("%a %d %b"), (first_date + i.days)]
    end
    dates
  end
```

`f.object.start.change({min: 0}).to_s` generates Version B

**Update**

It seems like 'optionising' the dates is modifying them.

Here's the HTML produced when turned to an option:

```
<option value="2015-11-12T14:41:15+00:00">Thu 12 Nov</option>
```

Here's the normal value:

```
<%= dates[3] %>
```

generates:

```
["Fri 13 Nov", Fri, 13 Nov 2015 00:00:00 +0000]
```

Comment: Can you keep them both as DateTime objects?  That will make the comparison a lot easier.  Also, if you're comparing dates, then use Date objects instead:  it will save you messing around with all the "midnight" stuff.

Comment: Also, edit your question and add the code where you're actually comparing them.

Comment: They're all already datetime objects, and the place where I'm actually comparing them is the "Context in my view". This code compares one of the dates, to the :selected value.

Comment: `[*0..100].each` can be simplified to `(0..100).each`

Comment: Since you do not care about the hour/minutes part, you should use `Date` objects instead. Eventually add `(first_date + i.days).to_date` to take off hours/minutes/seconds of the select's value and `f.object.start.to_date` in the selected option

Comment: I have some other fields that keep the time part, lower down in that view. This is just the dropdown to help people select the correct date. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version B is time with timezone, the version A is without the timezone. I would suggest you to use `Tome.zone.now` instead of `DateTime.now`

And there is one more issue with your code: you can use the default value for the argument like this: `def dates(first_date=DateTime.now)`, but you better not to. The problem is, that the `DateTime.now` will be executed, when your code will be loaded by the ruby interpreter, and the default value will not change anymore, not until you reaload your server.

So my suggestion would be to change the code to this:

```
def dates(start_time = nil)
  start_time = Time.zone.now if start_time.nil?
  first_date = date.midnight
```

Comment: Thanks for flagging the issue! But I am looking to keep everything in the DateTime format. Any reason why a Postgres-stored DateTime would give a different output to DateTime.now?

Comment: When Rails reads the column from the db, which is stored as Datetime, it converts it to time with timezone, because it's a preferred way to work with time.